# "Hello, World" smart contract using browser solidity

Tags: remix

Can any one provide end to end example "Hello, World" smart contract using browser solidity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as simple as it could be, but possibly more illustrative.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract HelloWorld {

    string saySomething;

    constructor() public  {
        saySomething = "Hello World!";
    }

    function speak() public constant returns(string itSays) {
        return saySomething;
    }

    function saySomethingElse(string newSaying) public  returns(bool success) {
        saySomething = newSaying;
        return true;
    }

}
```

It says "Hello World!", and we can change the message:

[image]

So when we summon it to speak, we get the new message:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: pl send the steps to be followed to execute this , because whenever i put some message in saySomethingElse and clikc on speak , it only displays string it Says  hello world instaed of message

Comment: Clicking "speak" executes the `speak()` function. You need to click on the pink "saySomethingElse" to execute the `saySomethingElse()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Answer by [Rob Hitchens - B9lab](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/5549/rob-hitchens-b9lab) worked! I did face an error due to difference in version.In case you are using solidity version > 0.5.0, some changes that were required:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract HelloWorld {

    string saySomething;

    constructor() public  {
        saySomething = "Hello World!";
    }

    function speak() public view returns(string memory) {
        return saySomething;
    }

    function saySomethingElse(string memory newSaying) public  returns(bool success) {
        saySomething = newSaying;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating that 2017 answer.